# Is there a way to save JavaScript DOM manipulations?

Tags: javascript

For example if JavaScript performs a bunch of manipulations on a table, the new HTML will not be visible via View -> Source.  Is there some way to capture JavaScript manipulations and save everything as a plain HTML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view it in a DOM inspector like Firebug or IE Developer tools

Comment: You can copy elements out of the dom inspectors to notepad etc

Comment: IE even has a save as html document built in from developer tools :-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to call

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

This will get the same output as view source except that it will have all the DOM manipulations visible. It will probably be missing the DOCTYPE however. I realized that the Webkit Console was printing the doctype fine, but there is no public API for getting the DOCTYPE, so you'll have to do that yourself.

A little bookmarklet that you can add to your browser to view the dom:

```
javascript:(function(){win=open(%22about:blank%22,%20%22View%20DOM%20Source%22,%20%22menubar=no,resizable=yes,status=no,toolbar=no%22);win.document.write(%22<pre>%22%20+%20document.documentElement.outerHTML.split(%22&%22).join(%22&amp;%22).split(%20%22<%22).join(%22&lt;%22).split(%22>%22).join(%22&gt;%22)%20+%20%22</pre>%22);win.focus();})()
```

(Sorry, can't post a Javascript Link).

Comment: What about `document.documentElement.outerHTML` ? In OP's case we can assume there is a `body` node, but in general, it is theoretically possible, I suppose, that there might be none.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `prompt("test",document.body.innerHTML);` and copy & paste the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the serialized current state of the table with `innerHTML`.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

table.innerHTML; // "<tbody><tr><td>..."

table.parentNode.innerHTML; // gets the serialization of the whole table, including the <table> tag
```

Comment: For the last thing it's better to use `table.outerHTML` rather then going through the parent node as that will return siblings as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I came across a method to capture and save DOM manipulations using `shell.js` and thought would list over here in case anyone is interested.

Assuming all DOM manipulations are complete.
After that.

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var data = window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
shell.echo(data).to("your/original/file.html");
```

That simple. 
I found it useful especially in node.js related DOM manipulations with `jsdom` (which apparently doesn't save DOM manipulations on its own).

Note: This will overwrite original file.